# Making JTextField accept mixed String , whet documentFIlter alow only digits

Tags: java, jtextfield, documentfilter

I have unusual issue something is working a bit to well. I have written a `DocumentFilter` witch allow user input only as numbers, `DocumentFilter` add dash on it's own in proper place during writing. This way in`JTextField`  is visible  date like this is: "2016-05-01". The problem is that `JTextField`   is not always filled in by user, sometimes it must be set by program. But when I use code setText("2016-05-01"), it don't display properly, all dash are gone. How to make it work ? 
I tried to  change `DocumentFilter` to allow dash, but this why cause problems in many other places. I probably will end up writting another `DocumentFilter` just for this but maybe there is a other way? Is it possible to append `JTextField`    char by char ? Is there a way to switch on an off the  `DocumentFilter`, or mayby it's posible to change smartly `DocumentFilter` so it will not crush in oder palces and work here as well? Below part of code  for `DocumentFilter`

```
  public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str,
    AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {

if (str == null || str.equals(""))
{
    super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a); 
}
else
{
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(str);
    for (int i = buffer.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    char ch = buffer.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isDigit(ch))
    {
        buffer.deleteCharAt(i);
    }
    }

    str = buffer.toString();
    //sign and sign2 is char number were separator(sep) is written 
    if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length() == sign)
    {
    str = str + sep;
    }
    if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length() == sign2)
    {
    str = str + sep;
    }


    if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length() - length) <= maxCharacters)
    super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
    else
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setText("20160501")` ?

Comment: Yes ,it give the same result as "2016-05-01" . In both cases it shows 20160501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
    if (str == null || str.equals("")) {
        super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
    } else {
        // check if 'str' contains 8 digits
        if (str.matches("^\\d{8}$")) {
            // add the dashes
            super.replace(fb, offs, length, str.replaceAll("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "$1-$2-$3"), a);
        } else {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(str);
            for (int i = buffer.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                char ch = buffer.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                    buffer.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
            }

            str = buffer.toString();
            // sign and sign2 is char number were separator(sep) is written
            if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length() == sign) {
                str = str + sep;
            }
            if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length() == sign2) {
                str = str + sep;
            }

            if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length() - length) <= maxCharacters)
                super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
            else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
}
```

and set the text using this:

```
textField.setText("20160420");
```